# Putting existentials into monad

Tags: haskell, monads, polymorphism

I have following problem. I have value of type `(forall r. MyType r)` and I need `ParsecT s u m (forall r. MyType r)`. Is it possible to do it without suppling additional `data` structures?

Comment: The best answer here may depend on what you're trying to accomplish overall. Existential types are awkward to work with.

Comment: The type you have is not existential, it's polymorphic.

Comment: @svenningsson: It's a quirk of how GHC Haskell implements existential types that they can look like universal types when inappropriately taken out of context. Assuming he does, in fact, have an existential type he'd need something like `forall t. (forall r. MyType r -> t) -> t`, i.e., there is some specific type `r` but you don't know what type it is, so you can only apply to it functions polymorphic in their argument.

Comment: The type I gave and the (presumably incorrect) polymorphic type Maciej wrote are related by the obvious quasi-CPS-transform, but in this case the meaning is indeed subtly different, unlike the usual `forall t. (A -> t) -> t` (for some concrete A) type of continuations.

Comment: Embarrassingly, it also *just now* occurred to me that this is not at all surprising, since undoing a CPS transform on an existential type amounts to something like double-negation elimination on an existence proof, which is not terribly constructive. Hunh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, if you have a true existential type, it's not allowed to "escape" into broader scope. The type `(forall r. MyType r)` means "this is a `MyType r` for any `r` you can think of", much like `Nothing` is of type `forall a. Maybe a`; it doesn't mean that there exists some unknown `r` such that you have a `MyType` of it.

If you actually want a polymorphic term, that's another matter entirely, but I'll assume you really did mean existential.

As I mentioned in the comments on the question, existential types represent a value with a specific but unknown type. Because you don't know the type, all you can do with such a value is apply to it a function which is polymorphic in its argument. There's no way to talk about an existential type directly, so the brief answer to your question is: No.

In order to manipulate an existential type, you can either hide them inside a continuation with a type like `forall t. (forall r. MyType r -> t) -> t`, or hide them in a data structure like `data ExistMyType = forall r. ExistMyType (MyType r)`. In fact, these are pretty much the same thing, since the continuation amounts to a Church encoding of the data type.

But honestly, I suspect that what you *really* should do is reconsider your approach. Existential types are awkward, a bit confusing, and usually not the best solution in Haskell. In particular I'm dubious that anything resembling the type you wrote would actually be useful. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: I was trying to enforce properties of tree (in this case - no loops) and I get into existentials when I tried to abstract the transformations.

Comment: @Maciej Piechotka: I suspected it was something like that, but I'm still doubtful it'll work very well in Haskell; what you're trying to do pretty much cries out for dependent types. If you're reasonably comfortable with the more math-oriented side of Haskell then I'd quite seriously encourage you to look into using Agda for the parsing and tree construction code.

Comment: I will look on it when I have free time - but for several reasons not in this task.